# Trying to Flatten a json Dataframe in Scala, which has special characters and also "/"

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, flatten

```
val jsonString_new = """
{"ExportSchema":[{"Application":"fuzzitDwh","EntityType":"4","CountryCode":"AT","ExportType":"DIFF","ExportUtcDateTime":"2021-12-15T01:45:01","LastExportUtcDateTime":"2021-12-14T10:19:37","FileName":"UL_DataLake_fuzzitDwh_MaterialExternal_AT_DIFF_20211215_014501.json"}],"ExportData":[{"Country/":[{"Country/Code":"AT","MaterialExternal":[{"WholesalerCode":" A__METR","M%at-erial()+ ExternalCode":"26780","Attributes":{"Name":"KALBSFOND HELL PASTOES 1KG KNR"}},{"WholesalerCode":"A__ESVP","M%at-erial()+ ExternalCode":"38636","Attributes":{"MaterialInternalCodeFromWholesaler":"38636","Name":"B&J 465ml Netflix&Chill'd CL1x8x180EB"}},{"WholesalerCode":"A__ESVP","M%at-erial()+ ExternalCode":"39767","Attributes":{"MaterialInternalCodeFromWholesaler":" 39767","Name":"B&J 170G ChocChipCookieDghCL3b X8x147EB"}}]}]}]}
""".stripMargin
```

```
val json_df = spark.read.json(Seq(jsonString_new).toDS) 

def flatten_json(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  val fields = df.schema.fields
  val fieldNames = fields.map(x => x.name)

  for (i <- fields.indices) {
    val field = fields(i)
    val fieldType = field.dataType
    val fieldName = field.name
    fieldType match {
      case _: ArrayType =>
        val fieldNamesExcludingArray = fieldNames.filter(_ != fieldName)
        val fieldNamesAndExplode = fieldNamesExcludingArray ++ Array(
          s"explode_outer($fieldName) as $fieldName"
        )
        val explodedDf = df.selectExpr(fieldNamesAndExplode: _*)
        return flatten_json(explodedDf)
      case structType: StructType =>
        val childFieldNames =
          structType.fieldNames.map(childname => fieldName + "." + childname)
        val newFieldNames = fieldNames.filter(_ != fieldName) ++ childFieldNames
        import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

        val renamedCols =
          newFieldNames.map { x =>
            col(x.toString).as(x.toString.replace(".", "_"))
          }

        val explodedDf = df.select(renamedCols: _*)
        return flatten_json(explodedDf)
      case _ =>
    }
  }

  df
}
val flattened_Df = flatten_json(json_df)
```

Error:

> AnalysisException: Column 'ExportData_Country_Country' does not exist.
> Did you mean one of the following? [ExportData_Country_Country/Code,
> ExportSchema_CountryCode, ExportData_Country_MaterialExternal,
> ExportData_Country_MaterialExternal, ExportSchema_Application,
> ExportSchema_EntityType, ExportSchema_ExportType,
> ExportSchema_FileName, ExportSchema_ExportUtcDateTime,
> ExportSchema_LastExportUtcDateTime]; line 1 pos 0; 'Project
> [ExportSchema_Application#52091, ExportSchema_CountryCode#52092,
> ExportSchema_EntityType#52093, ExportSchema_ExportType#52094,
> ExportSchema_ExportUtcDateTime#52095, ExportSchema_FileName#52096,
> ExportSchema_LastExportUtcDateTime#52097,
> unresolvedalias(('ExportData_Country_Country / 'Code),
> Some(org.apache.spark.sql.Column$$Lambda$6738/2007565455@225acd0)),
> ExportData_Country_MaterialExternal#52112]
> +- Generate explode(ExportData_Country_MaterialExternal#52099), true, [ExportData_Country_MaterialExternal#52112]

I can understand that anything after "/" is not being considered. Is there a way to deal with this?

Comment: It's not so easy to answer how to fix it since it's not easy to see what exactly you're doing.  Here is your original json pretty printed https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/1138e81b32f53b9a6686c5341d91902b What json are trying to transform it to? What exactly is flattening?